# How to multipy two 4D TensorVariable, python

Tags: python, tensorflow, theano

I have two 4D TensorVariable, `X=[100,1,28,28]` and `W=[100,1,28,28]`. The `X` is including `100` images (one-channel) with the size of `(28,28)`. The `W` is its corresponding weights for the `100` images. We want to multiply each image to its weights. In another word, I want `100` image in which each individual image comes from `T.dot(a,b)` where `a` is one image and `b` is its weight.

`T.dot(X,W)` is not working for me because it gives me a 5D TensorVariable.

Comment: So each element in `X` is multiplied by the corresponding element in `W`? And why did you add the Theano tag? Are you working with Tensorflow or Theano?

Comment: yes. Each element in `X` is multiplied by the corresponding element in `W`

Comment: Ok, and you are mentioning both Tensorflow and Theano. These are two very different libraries - which one are you using?

Comment: I am using Theano. I have  changed Tensorflow to TensorVariable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Theano [`T.dot`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.dot) function is a matrix multiplication (inner product). You want an element-wise multiplication, which, as described in the [documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#operator-support), is simply done using the `*` operator, i.e.

```
X * W
```

Comment: So here, each element of `X` is multiplied (inner product) by the corresponding element in `W`?

Comment: Exactly. This also supports NumPy-like broadcasting, e.g. if you have a `[1,1,28,28]` weight matrix, each of the 100 images will be multiplied by `W`. Note that it has to be `[1,1,28,28]` and not e.g. only `[28,28]`